# Get Cognito user pools groups data in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito user pool for authentication in AWS. When an authorized user hits an API, I want to get the Cognito user pool group in which user present. I have tried many ways like

```
{
    "role" : "$context.identity.role",
}
```

and

```
{
    "arn": $context.identity.userArn
}
```

(Above are just examples I have tried)

But, I am getting data as an empty string. Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the Cognito Identity Service Provider from the AWS SDK.

You can retrieve the user sub (subject) from event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider as follows:

```
let userSub = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider.split('CognitoSignIn:')[1]
let UserPoolId = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider.split(',')[0].split('/')[1]
```

You would use this along with the user pool id which can also be extracted from the above value in the listUsers function of the Cognito Identity Service Provider to retrieve the users Username:

```
let userParams = {
    UserPoolId,
    Filter: 'sub=\"' + userSub + '\"',
    Limit: 1
  }

  try {
    const users = await cognitoISP.listUsers(userParams).promise()
    Username = users.Users[0].Username
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle your error
  }
```

see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property

This Username along with the User Pool Id would then be used with the adminListGroupsForUser function from the Cognito Identity Service Provider to retrieve an array of the groups the user belongs to:

```
 try {
    let data = await cognitoISP.adminListGroupsForUser({
      UserPoolId,
      Username
    }).promise()
    groups = data.Groups
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle your error
  }
```

see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminListGroupsForUser-property

Your lambda functions would need to have access to the following on your cognito user pool:

```
- cognito-idp:ListUsers
- cognito-idp:AdminListGroupsForUser
```

see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the context in the authorizer, that context will be accessible in the lambda by `event.requestContext.authorizer`

note this is by adding the context on the authorizer response

```
{
  Version: "",
  Statement: ...,
  Context: {
     myProperty: "something"
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

EDIT:
Just noticed that you might be using cognito authorizer instead of the custom authorizer, which in that case this might help you

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238437

you suppose to get the user information through

```
$context.authorizer.claims.sub
```

Comment: I am able to get the data using `{"Authorization" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')"}` which is JWT encoded one. Here my question is using the token data and groups data(like belongs to admin or guest which is defined in user pool authorizer) can I do authentication restrict for accessing API endpoints in lambda function?

Comment: yes you can, you just need to setup that in your lambda. You can fetch your user data to cognito and use that information to provide the correct authorizer response just like here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html